# Canvas collision

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am a new in javascript and trying to find out how to make a collision with ball and plank which will stop the game and alert player with something like "You lost". But I only want red balls to hit the plank and blue to pass on without touching. Here is code that I am working on. (I dont mind if you could help to do collision only with both balls)

```
var spawnRate = 100;

var spawnRateOfDescent = 2;

var lastSpawn = -10;

var objects = [];

var startTime = Date.now();

function spawnRandomObject() {


var t;

if (Math.random() < 0.50) {
    t = "red";
} else {
    t = "blue";
}


var object = {
    type: t,
    x: Math.random() * (canvas.width - 30) + 15,
    y: 0

}

objects.push(object);
}



function animate() {

var time = Date.now();

if (time > (lastSpawn + spawnRate)) {
    lastSpawn = time;
    spawnRandomObject();
}

for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    var object = objects[i];
    object.y += spawnRateOfDescent;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(object.x, object.y, 8, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = object.type;
    ctx.fill();

    }

    }



var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var paddleHeight = 10;
var paddleWidth = 60;
var paddleY = 480
var paddleX = (canvas.width-paddleWidth)/2;
var rightPressed = false;
var leftPressed = false;

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

function keyDownHandler(e) {
if(e.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = true;
}
else if(e.keyCode == 37) {
    leftPressed = true;
}
}
function keyUpHandler(e) {
if(e.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = false;
}
else if(e.keyCode == 37) {
    leftPressed = false;
}
}



function drawPaddle() {
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(paddleX, paddleY, paddleWidth, paddleHeight);
ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
}




function draw() {
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
drawPaddle();    
animate();

if(rightPressed && paddleX < canvas.width-paddleWidth) {
    paddleX += 3;
}
else if(leftPressed && paddleX > 0) {
    paddleX -= 3;
}

}

setInterval(draw, 10);
```

Thanks!

Comment: You will have to check whether boxes are overlapping each other every time you are about to draw (math wise, keep in mind its easier to see that the boxes _are not_ overlapping than that they _are_)... Also, you might want to _indent your code_ - it is much easier to read and help with.

Comment: You will get a smoother animation by using [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead of `setInterval`.

Comment: Please don't deface your questions.

Comment: I can't delete them

Comment: Why are you trying to delete the question?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an object like this:

```
let ball = { type: 'red', x: 10, y: 10, width: 10, height: 10 };
```

You might want to consider adding a method to this to check if it overlaps any other rectangle:

```
ball.overlapsBall = function( otherBall ){
    return !( 
        otherBall.x + otherBall.width < this.x 
        && otherBall.y + otherBall.height < this.y 
        && otherBall.y > this.y + this.height 
        && otherBall.x > this.x + this.height
    );
}
```

You do this by checking if it *does not overlap*, which is only true if one box is entirely outside of the other (have a read through the if statement and try to visualise it, its actually rather simple)

In your draw function you could now add a loop to see if any overlap occurs:

```
var overlap = objects.filter(function( ball ) { return paddle.overlapsBall( ball ) });
```

You could even place an `if` statement to check it's type! (The `filter` will take you entire array of balls and check the overlaps, and remove anything from the array that does not return `true`. Now you can use `overlaps.forEach(function( ball ){ /* ... */});` to do something with all the balls that overlapped your paddle.)

One last thing, if you are planning on doing this with many objects you might want to consider using a simple class like this for every paddle or ball you make:

```
class Object2D {

    constructor(x = 0, y = 0;, width = 1, height = 1){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = x;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    overlaps( otherObject ){
        !( otherObject.x + otherObject.width < this.x && otherObject.y + otherObject.height < this.y && otherObject.y > this.y + this.height && otherObject.x > this.x + this.height );
    }

}
```

This allows you to this simple expression to create a new object that automatically has a method to check for overlaps with similar objects:

```
var paddle = new Object2D(0,0,20,10);
var ball = new Object2D(5,5,10,10);
paddle.overlaps( ball ); // true!
```

On top of that, you are *ensured* that any `Object2D` contains the values you will need for your calculations. You can check if this object is if the right type using `paddle instanceof Object2D` (which is `true`).

**Note** Please note, as @Janje so continuously points out in the comments below, that we are doing a rectangle overlap here and it might create some 'false positives' for all the pieces of rectangle that aren't the circle. This is good enough for most cases, but you can find the math for other overlaps and collisions easily ith a quick google search.

### Update: Simple Implementation

See below for a very simple example of how overlaps work in action:

```js
var paddle = { x: 50,  y: 50,  width: 60,  height: 20 };
var box = { x: 5, y: 20, width: 20, height: 20 };

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

document.body.appendChild( canvas );

canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 300;

function overlaps( a, b ){
  return !!( a.x + a.width > b.x &&  a.x < b.x + b.width
    && a.y + a.height > b.y &&  a.y < b.y + b.height );
}

function animate(){
  ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
  
  ctx.fillStyle = overlaps( paddle, box ) ? "red" : "black";
  ctx.fillRect( paddle.x, paddle.y, paddle.width, paddle.height );
  ctx.fillRect( box.x, box.y, box.width, box.height );
 
  window.requestAnimationFrame( animate );
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){
  paddle.x = event.clientX - paddle.width / 2;
  paddle.y = event.clientY - paddle.height / 2;
})

animate();
```

Comment: Circle-rectangle is not the same as rectangle-rectangle collision.

Comment: Most of the time it is _good enough_, certainly when starting out. The question was regarding more general collision technique. You can replace the collision function with any other out there. (also, its not like rectangle-rectangle does not work for circles either)

Comment: Are you just _trying_ to nitpick? We are checking for collision and the object is called `ball`.  If it is overlapping it is colliding. I don't see your issue here. If you have a better solution, you can always post an answer yourself. And if you are talking edge cases or semantics, that's not really the point here.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that representing a ball with a rectangle will not work well. At times the balls will be collected before the actual hit, at other times you will be able to save balls that should've passed.

Comment: Yes @janje, I am aware of that. However, it is actually _good enough for most cases_. The OP is obviously trying something new here, and complicating things by calculating circle-rectangle collisions might be making things too complex for their own good. For the purpose of this, rectangle-rectangle will do just fine.

Comment: You should've mentioned that you were using an approximation which will not work well in all cases (and I wouldn't call 10%+ of cases edge cases).

Comment: @Janje - Sigh you are resilient. Fine, I'll mention it but I don't necessarily agree with how you brought it up. Next time try to offer changes helpfully in the comments, and not as a single 'critique' comment with no addition other than 'It's not this thing'.

Comment: @somethinghere.  You're probably getting some pushback because circle-rectangle collisions are a well known quantity. But you are correct that rect-rect collision testing works fine here because the circle is dropping exactly vertically -- rather than at a non-axis aligned angle. Even simpler than rect-rect testing is to test if the bottom of the ball has reached the top of the paddle: `ball.y+ball.radius>paddle.y`. If no, the test is done (no collision). If yes, continue to test if the ball is horizontally aligned with the paddle. Cheers!

Comment: @markE This is the kind of comment I appreciate more! Expanding and improving on ideas is much more helpful. Thanks for the addition!

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't really help me to do what I want.

Comment: @Anthony it might be useful if your comment is explaining _why that is_ instead of just saying 'nope'.

Comment: @somethinghere I am just trying to find out how to implement collision code into my code. And you are talking about creating new variable and then work from there which means I will have to rewrite everything. So instead of that I am going to do if statement and check if ball will be in the same position as paddle and if it's true then stop the game. I tryed doing if (object.x == paddleX && object.y == paddleY) but it doesn't seem to be working. :(

Comment: The odds of the ball and paddle being in _exactly_ the same position is exactly  why you need to check overlaps. You can easily rewrite this code to work seperately from the object, like in a function (`function overlaps(a, b){ return !( a.x +a.width < b.x && a.y + a.height < b.y && a.y > b.y + b.height && a.x > b.x + b.height ); }`. The thing is, you _need_ some variables and you will enjoy your code a lot more if it is structured correctly. However, as long as you have width, height, x and y of any object you should be able to calculate overlaps like this.

Comment: @somethinghere Doesn't work, I tryed doing if statement instead of function to make it easier but its not working as well.

Comment: This is how you check if rectangles overlap, what more can i say? If the rectangle is to the left,bottom, right or top it won't overlap otherwise it's overlapping. Just to be clear,if you are drawing circles with canvas you are drawing fromthe center,so your x and y get reduced by the radius for rectangle overlap. Otherwise, i cant help you more withoutmore code. Try to visualise it...

Comment: Either way, this tells you overlaps as well. Collision and overlaps are the same thing. Collision is when moving, overlaps is when you freeze the frame. If you have `box1` and `box2` then `if( box1.x + box1.width > box2.x && box1.x < box2.x + box2.width && box1.y + box1.height > box2.y && box1.y < box2.y + box2.height ){ /* They are overlapping */ }`

Comment: Thanks for help anyway if I find solution I ll post it.

Comment: @somethinghere I think my collision code somehow affects my moving code and it doesn't work. Any suggestions? Thats what I have:

Comment: function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawPaddle();    
 animate();
 
    if(rightPressed && paddleX < canvas.width-paddleWidth) {
        paddleX += 3;
    }
    else if(leftPressed && paddleX > 0) {
        paddleX -= 3;
    }

 if( object.x + object.width > paddleX && object.x < paddleX + paddleWidth && object.y + object.height > paddleY && object.y < paddleY + paddleHeight ){
    alert("hello")
 }
}

Comment: I'm afraid I can't really debug your code as it's hard to pinpoint _what_ is going wrong. Have a look at my sample implementation above and let me know if it makes it clearer.

Comment: I did the collision code by adding this   ' var distX = Math.abs(object.x - paddleX-paddleWidth/2);
    var distY = Math.abs(object.y - paddleY-paddleHeight/2);
  
 if (distX > (paddleWidth/2 + 8)) { return false; }
 if (distY > (paddleHeight/2 + 8)) { return false; }
 
 if (distX <= (paddleWidth/2)) { alert("hey"); }
 if (distY <= (paddleHeight/2)) { alert("hey"); }
 }    '

Comment: But now I have different problem, balls wouldn't spawn, only one ball would spawn and thats it. I am gonna try figure that out for now.

Comment: Why work in distances like this? You are going to confuse yourself very fast. Justwork with objects and use the universal overlapping method. Stop making things harder by trying to make your code work and start looking at existing examples to find out how you should structure and think aboutyour code.

Comment: I am finding code that works, the one I found worked for me so now I am a step closer to figuring out whole thing, thanks for trying to help anyway :)